# how can I reduce the tokenizer loading time?

Tags: performance, loading, tokenize

Tokenizer in huggingface is too slow to load. it takes normally 8s. I have no idea why it takes so long.

when I tried to load the vocab from my local, it takes 50ms. judging by this, weight loading from huggingface makes it load slow. but the problem is AutoTokenizer has no function that load from the local path.... I have to use AutoTokenizer because of the word_id() function. so is there anyone knows why AutoTokenizer is so slot to load?

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import time

start = time()
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
end = time()-start
print(f"Loading Time : {round(end, 2)}s")

# 7.23s
```

when I tried to use BertTokenizer or something for using local path, it took really fast.